# Phone stops charging when PC is idle. What can cause this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, pop-os

I connect my Android phone to my PC via USB cable, and it seems like it stops charging after some time when I am away. After I come back and touch the mouse the charging resumes.

There is no sleep/hibernation, only screens turn off. Some time ago it was working fine. PopOS 21.04.

`cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` is `-1` (added `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to boot params via `kernelstub`).

The PC is definitely not sleeping, there are `journalctl` logs during that time.
https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/7ed45ddcc677fccd1fa46a0294890131

Comment: How do you determine that the system does not go in a low-power mode turning things like this off?   That said, there frequently is a USB-port on laptop for charging that is not affected by this.  Perhaps you were using that before?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How do I determine that it does? :)
I tried 2 ports in different places. It is a desktop, Asrock Z390 Taichi Ultimate motherboard.

Comment: Do you have power saving enabled, does your system suspend when you walk away? If it does it explains everything.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Not sure which power saving things to check, but definitely no suspend. See the last paragraph.

Comment: Check the manuals for the computer

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it seems like the issue is on the OS/software level. I did not touch anything in the BIOS settings for months, and several weeks ago it was working fine in the same USB port.